# Downloading a folder in VBS

Tags: http, networking, vbscript, get, download

I want to download a folder or individual files but the way that I am downloading files I don't know the file names so this is why I want the folder to be downloaded then I can have the folder saved to over write or add the additional files to the output folder. 
For individual files I am using

```
Set args = WScript.Arguments
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
Url = "http://webpage.com/downloads"
dim xHttp: Set xHttp = createobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
dim bStrm: Set bStrm = createobject("Adodb.Stream")
xHttp.Open "GET", Url, False
xHttp.Send


with bStrm
    .type = 1 '//binary
    .open
    .write xHttp.responseBody
    .savetofile "C:\Users\"&objNetwork.UserName&"\AppData\Roaming\downloadfolderarea", 2 '//overwrite
    .end with
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: XMLHttpRequests don't work that way. If you want to download an entire folder, directory listing must be enabled on the server, you must extract the file URLs from the directory listing, and download them one by one.

Comment: Ansgar since I am downloading this from a server that I own how would I do this (all I have is FTP and SSH). It is cent OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest` objects don't support FTP or SSH. You have to use the appropriate clients for those protocols, e.g. `ftp.exe` (for FTP) or tools from the [PuTTY suite](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/plink.exe) (for SSH/SCP/SFTP). I'd prefer the latter, since you can use public key authentication instead of dealing with username/password.

The aforementioned clients are scriptable and you can execute them from VBScript using the [`Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky) method. Example for `plink`:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run "C:\path\to\pscp.exe -i key user@host:/path/to/src C:\dst"
```